vercel/speed-insights peer dependency issue
'Log files:
/Users/arip995/.npm/_logs/2024-06-25T04_44_44_677Z-debug-0.log
npm resolution error report
While resolving: @vercel/speed-insights@1.0.12
Found: next@14.3.0-canary.31
node_modules/next
next@"^14.3.0-canary.31" from the root project
Could not resolve dependency:
peerOptional next@">= 13" from @vercel/speed-insights@1.0.12
node_modules/@vercel/speed-insights
@vercel/speed-insights@"*" from the root project
Conflicting peer dependency: next@14.2.4
node_modules/next
peerOptional next@">= 13" from @vercel/speed-insights@1.0.12
node_modules/@vercel/speed-insights
@vercel/speed-insights@"*" from the root project
Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
--legacy-peer-deps but it fails in prod and it is not the right solution.
